# The platform toolset for Windows phone 8.1(v120_wp81) appears as not installed in vs2013 update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, build-tools, vcxproj

I want to upgrade my project from Windows phone 8.0 to Windows phone 8.1. But i'm not getting the required platform toolset for windows phone 8.1(v120_wp81) in the dropdown in properties->general->platform toolset. I have vs2013 with update 4.

I tried to manually change the platform toolset to the required version in the .vcxproj file, but after reloading the project, the platform toolset appears as not installed.

Can anyone suggest if i'm missing out anything here.

Comment: Got it resolved. You have to add these tags in your vcxproj file. <ApplicationType>Windows Phone</ApplicationType>
<ApplicationTypeRevision>8.1</ApplicationTypeRevision>

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped me. In my *.vcxproj* file the *ApplicationType* was initially set to *Windows Store* and the build then failed. But when I changed *ApplicationType* to *Windows Phone* compilation succeeded. I think you should upgrade your comment to an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Got it resolved. You have to add these tags in your vcxproj file. ApplicationType as Windows Phone and ApplicationTypeRevision as 8.1.